# Simple file launcher and directory navigator sought for 14.04

Tags: 14.04, launcher, cinnamon

I am a new Ubuntu 14.04 user, transitioning from Linux Mint 17.3.  In Mint, I depended on an ultra-simple file launcher - directory navigator applet for Cinnamon, entitled "Places Center."

https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/128

I assumed that I'd easily find an equivalent in Ubuntu, but have looked and looked, to no avail!  The Main Menu app will let me add programs to Classic Menu Indicator, but that's not really what I'm after.  All I want is a simple tree to click open frequently-used word processor files, to navigate to frequently-accessed directories and so forth.

If anyone can recommend one, I'll be grateful.

Comment: You can install the Cinnamon Desktop Environment in Ubuntu, which should bring that applet with it.

Comment: Thank you!  I never thought of that!  -- Would you recommend the technique at:  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/07/new-cinnamon-ubuntu-14-04-ppa-stable -- or is there a better one?

Answer (score 1):

You can just install the Cinnamon Desktop Environment in Ubuntu. That'll give you your old experience on your new OS.

Run these commands to install Cinnamon:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moorkai/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Log out, click the gear icon next to your username, and choose Cinnamon before logging back in.

Comment: I wound up using: https://launchpad.net/~kranich/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon -- and it works splendidly, at least so far.  Thank you, Zacharee1; you've brought hours of frustration to an end!